# The power set $P(X)$ of a finite set $X$ is a bilinear space over $F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

In the book of Kazimierz Szymiczek (Algebra, Logic and Applications)  Bilinear Algebra An Introduction to the Algebraic Theory of Quadratic Forms, page 18. I have found that the power set $(P(X),+,\cdot)$ of a finite set $X$ is a bilinear space over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ by the rules:
$$\forall A,B\in P(X),\qquad A+B:=A\Delta B=(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) $$
and the multiplication by a scalar is defined as
$$0\cdot A =\emptyset,\qquad 1\cdot A =A.$$
Next he defined the bilinear form $f$ on $P(X)$ by:
$$\forall A,B\in P(X),\quad f(A,B)=|A\cap B|\mod 2 $$
So for me, it is clear why $f(\lambda\cdot A,B)=\lambda\cdot f(A,B)$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}_2$, but it is not clear why this form is bilinear, exactly my problem is how to prove the linearity with respect to the first argument:
$$\big((A+B)\cap C\big)\ \text{ mod }2=(A\cap C)\  \text{mod } 2+(B\cap C)\ \text{mod 2}$$

Comment: $(A\triangle B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\triangle (B\cap C)$; because an element is on the left hand sice if and only if it is in $C$, and in either $A$ or $B$ but not both; and is on the right hand side if and only if it is either in $A$ and $C$, or in $B$ and $C$, but not in both. Now notice that $|A+B|\bmod 2 = |A|+|B|\bmod 2$, since $x\in A+B$ if and only if $\chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)\bmod 2 = 1$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Why |A+B| mod 2 = |A| mod 2 + |B| mod 2 ?

Comment: Use `\bmod 2`, not that mess you are using.

Comment: Because an element lies in $A+B$ if and only if it lies in exactly one of $A$ and $B$. $|A|=|A-B|+|A\cap B|$. $|B|=|B-A|+|A\cap B|$, $|A+B| = |A-B|+|B-A| = |A|+|B|-2|A\cap B| \equiv |A|+|B|\pmod{2}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Please I understand $ |A+B| \mod  2= ( |A|  + |B| )\mod 2$
but I don't understand why $ |A+B| \mod 2 = |A| \mod 2 + |B| \mod 2$

Comment: Please write MathJax correctly.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the symbols. I interpret the $+$ on the right to be addition modulo $2$. Otherwise, the formula should read $((|A|\bmod 2) + (|B|\bmod 2) \bmod 2)$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin  thank you, all is very good now.